# Trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

$$ 2^{\sin (x)} + 2^{\cos (x)} \geq 2^{\left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$

How does one solve this equation? Is there any method other than using the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: You can differentiate the left hand side. The minima is equal to $ 2^{(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}$. This happens when $x=5 \pi /4 + 2n\pi$

Comment: More precisely, these minima happen also to be the roots of  $2 \pi$ periodical function $f(x)=2^{(\sin x) } \ + \  2^{(\cos x)} \ - \ 2^{(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}$.